# Solving for a Tangent line

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable nonzero functions in a neighborhood of $x=2$, and $h=f/g$. I need to determine the line tangent to the graph of $y=g(x)$ at the point $(2,g(2))$ if the tangent line to $y=f(x)$ at $(2,f(2))$ is $12x-y-16=0$ and the tangent line to $y=h(x)$ at $(2,h(2))$ is $5x+4y-6=0$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What is the derivative of h, by quotient rule?

Comment: right, so its $[f'(c)g(c)-g'(c)f(c)]/g^2(c)$...

Comment: but i don't know g(c) or f(c)?

Comment: Remember the tangent line to a curve y=f(x) at x=c passes through (c,f(c))? Use that.

Comment: hmm, so f(2)=8, so it passes through (2,8), and g(2)=-1, so g(x) passes through (2,-1)?

Comment: $h(x)$ passes thru $(2,-1)$, not $g(x)$. Read the problem carefully.